# php rows with each row having a button that I want redirect to external page

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, rows

I have displayed 4 rows of a table (gids) from phpmyadmin.
Now I have added for each row a button, I want to redirect each button to an external page (book.php).  Now when I use the classname "data" in javascript to try to redirect to book.php, this doesn't work for all 4 buttons.
What should I change so these buttons work for each row?

```
        <div class="row">

    <?php 

    if(isset($_SESSION['FBID'])){


    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "phpproject");
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT gids_voornaam, gids_naam, gids_bio, gids_richting, gids_jaar, gids_stad FROM gids";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo 
'<div class="col-sm-4">'.
            "<br>".'<img class="img-rounded img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/150">'.
            "<br>"."voornaam: ".$row["gids_voornaam"].
            "<br>". "Achternaam: ". $row["gids_naam"].
            "<br>". "Richting: ". $row["gids_richting"].
            "<br>". "Jaar: ". $row["gids_jaar"].
            "<br>". "Biografie:  " . $row["gids_bio"]. 
            "<br>"."<br>".'<button type="submit" class="data" >boekingsdata</button>'.
'</div>';



     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
}


     ?>
         </div>



  <script>


var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('data');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.location.href = 'book.php';
});


  </script>
```

Comment: is this code inside a html form?
If your answer is "yes", then can you paste your form code?

Comment: <button type="button" not submit

Comment: you're using the SAME id for all of the buttons you output in the loop. that's illegal. a DOM ID must be unique.

Comment: @MárcioGonzalez: no I didn't use a html form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var **btn** is an **array** so you need to read as an array.

Try this:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('data');

for(var item in btn){
    btn[item].addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.location.href = 'book.php';
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your code, the result will be four rows, and each have a button at the end, right?

Because there is your problem: all buttons have the same ID: `id="dat"`

You can avoid this by creating a new variable to count the rows, then append the variable's value to each buttons ID, thus creating "dat1", "dat2", etc.

Modify this part:

```
// output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo 
'<div class="col-sm-4">'.
        "<br>".'<img class="img-rounded img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/150">'.
        "<br>"."voornaam: ".$row["gids_voornaam"].
        "<br>". "Achternaam: ". $row["gids_naam"].
        "<br>". "Richting: ". $row["gids_richting"].
        "<br>". "Jaar: ". $row["gids_jaar"].
        "<br>". "Biografie:  " . $row["gids_bio"]. 
        "<br>"."<br>".'<button type="submit" id="dat" class="data" >boekingsdata</button>'.
'</div>';



 }
```

Into this:

```
// output data of each row
 $counter = 1; //new variable
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo 
'<div class="col-sm-4">'.
        "<br>".'<img class="img-rounded img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/150">'.
        "<br>"."voornaam: ".$row["gids_voornaam"].
        "<br>". "Achternaam: ". $row["gids_naam"].
        "<br>". "Richting: ". $row["gids_richting"].
        "<br>". "Jaar: ". $row["gids_jaar"].
        "<br>". "Biografie:  " . $row["gids_bio"]. 
        "<br>"."<br>".'<button type="submit" id="dat' . $counter . '" class="data" >boekingsdata</button>'.
'</div>';
$counter++; //increment it with every row


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var btn = document.getElementById('data');
```

also change your button to

```
id='data'
```

and in function

```
window.location.href = 'book.php'; // here also try to give full url
```

Comment: only works for the first button of the first row, clicking on the other buttons doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('dat');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.location.href = 'book.php';
});
```

**UPDATE Based on your comments:**

1 - You'll need to build a `form`, example:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="book.php" method="post">
voornaam: <input type="text" name="voornaam" value="<?php echo $row["gids_voornaam"]?>"><?php echo $row["gids_voornaam"]?><br>
etc..
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

2 - After the user clicks the submit button, you'll need to get the `POST` values on `book.php`, example:

```
voornaam IS <?php echo $_POST["voornaam"]; ?><br>
```

You don't need javascript for this, just simple `html` and php on `backend`.

Comment: What do you need to do with the data from the DB when the user clicks the button ? as it is right now isn't submitting anything besides the button name. You'll need to build a form and post the contents to book.php

Comment: for the moment, clicking on the button should only create a link to another page (book.php)... so clicking doesn't do anything with the date from the DB.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense what you're asking. If you need just a link why don't you use the `a` tag ? `<a  href="book.php">book</a>` ?!

Comment: because I wanted to automatically create for each row a link to another page, doesn't matter if this a <a>-tag or a <button>-tag